# Applescript: GUI Programming for recursively printing to PDF for Appleworks

Tags: pdf, printing, io, applescript

**The Goal:** thousands of old Clarisworks and Appleworks documents need to become PDFs.

**The Problem:** Scripting Pages is not an option; it doesn't preserve formatting reliably. *It must be Appleworks*. This script works, when it works; but it skips files for reasons I cannot identify.

```
set appleworksFolder to choose folder
tell application "Finder"
    set folderItems to (files of entire contents of appleworksFolder)
    repeat with I from 1 to number of items in folderItems

        set the_doc to item I of folderItems
        set doc_name to name of the_doc as text

            (* Some files are missing metatags and try to save as "Untitled Document",
              this block ensures a file name is unique, later *)

            tell application "Finder"
            set the clipboard to doc_name & ".pdf"
        end tell


            (* Each file exists in a folder with a path.txt file that will later
               be used to put the file back where it was originally stored prior
               to this conversion process *)

        if name of the_doc is not "path.txt" then
            try
                tell application "Finder"

            (* Many files no longer have name extensions and appear as UNIX
               executables if not repaired *)

                    try
                        set nmex to name extension of the_doc as text
                    on error
                        set nmex to "ok"
                    end try

                    if nmex is not "cwk" or "CWK" then
                        set the_doc_str to the_doc as text
                        set doc_path to POSIX path of the_doc_str
                        do shell script "mv '" & doc_path & "' " & "'" & doc_path & ".cwk'"
                    end if
                    delay 1


            (* In case Appleworks hangs or otherwise bungs up, I force-quit
               it at the end of the script; this ensures its closed before 
               it tries to open the next file *)

                    if (application process "Appleworks 6" of application "System Events" exists) then
                        do shell script "killall 'LaunchCFMApp'"
                        delay 1
                    end if

                    tell application "AppleWorks 6"
                        open the_doc
                    end tell

            (* Some of the documents are huge, this delay gives the app time to load
                since this is all GUI-scripted *)

                    delay 5
                    tell application process "Appleworks 6" of application "System Events"

            (* This is where I think I am encountering problems; there are two 
               possible warnings that may or may not appear on opening the doc;
               that Appleworks needs to append a version number to the file (if
               its old) or that the file may be damaged and thus would need to be
               skipped. I get system beeps sometimes in this part, but I don't know
               why! *)

                        if (button "OK" of window 1 of application process "AppleWorks 6" of application "System Events" exists) then
                            delay 0.5
                            keystroke return
                            delay 0.5
                        end if
                        delay 2
                        if (button "OK" of window 1 of application process "AppleWorks 6" of application "System Events" exists) then
                            delay 0.5
                            keystroke return
                            delay 0.5
                        end if
                        delay 2
            (* If the document loads, the Appleworks welcome pane won't be there;
               this part of the script works flawlessly, when it happens. Sometimes
               documents are outside of print margins, hence the press-ok-button 
               conditional *)

                        if not (window "Starting Points" of application process "AppleWorks 6" of application "System Events" exists) then
                            tell application process "Appleworks 6" of application "System Events"
                                keystroke "p" using command down
                                delay 1
                                click menu button "PDF" of window "Print" of application process "AppleWorks 6" of application "System Events"
                                delay 1
                                click menu item "Save as PDF…" of menu "PDF" of menu button "PDF" of window "Print" of application process "AppleWorks 6" of application "System Events"
                                delay 1
                                keystroke "v" using command down
                                click button "Save" of window "Save" of application process "AppleWorks 6" of application "System Events"
                                delay 8
                                keystroke "w" using command down
                                delay 0.5
                                if (button 1 of window 1 of application process "AppleWorks 6" of application "System Events" exists) then
                                    delay 0.5
                                    keystroke "d" using command down
                                    delay 0.5
                                end if
                                delay 0.5
                            end tell
                        end if
                        do shell script "killall 'LaunchCFMApp'"
                        delay 3
                    end tell
                end tell
            end try
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

I want to this baby to just run through a couple of thousands files over a weekend and create PDFs, but each time I run it overnight I find a few hundred correctly processed documents, hundreds or thousands of skipped documents, and often a print dialogue for *the script itself*, which obviously comes from using Command+P outside of an Appleworks context. I'm an Applescript noob, to be sure, this has been driving me nuts for weeks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really a solution to your problem, as it is highly specific and tailored, but I have some possibly useful tips:

- You don't need to close the "Starting Points" window. It will be dismissed when you tell AppleWorks to open a document.
- Try to use as few simulated keystrokes as possible. For instance, instead of simulating `cmd+P` to open the Print dialog, it is better to simulate a click on the application's `Print…` command inside its `File` menu:

  ```
  click menu item "Print…" of menu "File" of menu bar 1 of application process "AppleWorks 6"
  ```

  and instead of performing a `cmd+W` to close the document, the proper way is to do

  ```
  tell application "AppleWorks 6" to close front document saving no
  ```
- If you do need to simulate keystrokes, ensure that they are received by the correct application, by activating it just before the `keystroke` command with a `tell app "AppleWorks 6" to activate`, just in case it wasn't the frontmost app at that point.
- When checking for additional dialog windows, it's a bad idea to use `if (button 1 of window 1 of (*...*) exists)`, because on my machine, for instance, checking this while the "Print" dialog was open caused the script to hang for minutes (possibly for good), and because it's always advisable to address a window by name rather than number (since `window 1` is simply the frontmost window, and that can quickly become another). So, it's better to check if a window named *such and such* exists.
- In order to process thousands of files where you expect errors to happen, you need to restructure your code and rethink the error handling. For instance, you could log error information to a text file in order to see which files have been skipped and why. To separate program logic from the error handling and details, you could use handlers, so your main loop could look like this:

  ```
  set logfile to alias "Macintosh HD:Users:user:Desktop:errors.log"
  open for access logfile with write permission

  repeat with the_doc in folderItems
      try
          open_with_appleworks(the_doc)
          print_to_pdf()
          close_document_and_quit_appleworks()
      on error error_message
          write error_message & "\n" to logfile
          close_document_and_quit_appleworks()
      end try
  end repeat

  close access logfile
  ```

  In a similar way, you can log success messages, too. In the single handlers, then, you are supposed to specify details about how exactly to do every step. They can also provide some error information to be logged:

  ```
  to open_with_appleworks(the_doc)
      tell app "AppleWorks 6"
          try
              (* do your stuff here *)
          on error err_msg
              (* re-signal the error to main loop! *)
              error "Failed to open " & (the_doc as text) & err_msg
          end try
      end tell
  end open_with_appleworks
  ```
- Hard-coded delays slow down your script considerably: while only *some* of your documents might take a few seconds to open, your script will *always* wait 5 seconds – even if the document opens instantaneously. It's better to have a loop check whether the document has opened yet:

  ```
  repeat while not (exists front document)
      -- just wait
      -- or, delay 0.1 -- if you really want to
  end repeat
  ```

  The same holds for nearly all your other delays, most of them can be avoided, as they will be much shorter *or longer* in practice. Instead of delaying half a second, hoping that the warning or dialog will have appeared by then, it's better to check whether it's there or not.
- (one last tip and then I'll be quiet) Unfortunately, you seem to already have gone through the trouble of copying all the files to be processed into one folder, remembering in some "path.txt" where they came from... This **can** be avoided if the files are in sub-folders of some folder and can be found by a filter: You just create a "smsart folder" with that specific search ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqpU3.png)), then say in your AppleScript `set theFiles to choose file with multiple selections allowed`, then select all files in that particular smart folder, and you're good. The script can then easily find out where a `file f` is by asking `application "Finder"` to `get parent of f` (that will return a Finder `file` reference, which can be easily converted to an `alias` and to a `POSIX file` address). Then, since you know the name and location of the PDF file generated by "printing" the document, you can move that PDF to the folder where its source document is.

Comment: This is just the sort of advice I was looking for——as a nub, it's going to take me some time to go implement these suggestions. But in general, this was what I wanted, a way to make this script robust enough to save me having to go and open 4000+ files by hand and save to PDF. Thanks a million for taking the time to write all this for me!!!

Comment: I do have one question though... Appleworks error windows don't seem to have titles, they don't use system dialogue boxes, which is why I was using "window 1". Any idea how I can retrieve this information?

Comment: In a state when an error window you want to target is shown, run a small test script to `tell application "System Events" to get properties of windows of application process "AppleWorks 6"`. This'll get you a list of dictionaries for the windows; for instance, dialog windows have a property `description:"dialog"`, which you can later check for (e.g. `exists window 1 and window 1's description is "dialog"`)